# PowerShell сложение вычитание данных из текста

Tags: powershell

Имеется файл с данными, в котором указаны фамилии, расход и приход:

```
Иванов
654.45
1078.21
Петров
246.85
1325.46
375.75
2746.11
Сидоров
456.25
258.41
```

Надо получить баланс по каждой фамилии

```
Иванов 423.76
Петров 3448.97
Сидоров -197.84
```

Расчёт происходит следующим образом:

```
Иванов -654.45 + 1078.21 = 423.76
Петров -246.85 + 1325.46 - 375.75 + 2746.11 = 3448.97
Сидоров -456.25 + 258.41 = -197.84
```

Расход/приход идёт парами первая строка расход, вторая приход.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать средствами Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Это явно не самое оптимальное решение, но рабочее:

```
$datafile="c:\ffmpeg\1.txt" 
$datalines = Get-Content $datafile
for($i=0; $i -le $datalines.Length;)
{
    $name = $datalines[$i]
    $i=$i+1
    [double]$difference = 0
    Do{
        $difference = $difference - ($datalines[$i] -as [double]) + ($datalines[$i+1] -as [double]) 
        $i=$i+2
    }While([double]::TryParse($datalines[$i] , [ref]$b ))

    Write-Host ($name, $difference)
}
```

[image: Результат работы скрипта]